# reshaped elements in different positions relative to original array - matlab

Tags: matlab, reshape

```
a=randn(4,4,2,3)

a(:,:,1,1) =
    0.5377    0.3188    3.5784    0.7254
    1.8339   -1.3077    2.7694   -0.0631
   -2.2588   -0.4336   -1.3499    0.7147
    0.8622    0.3426    3.0349   -0.2050

a(:,:,2,1) =
   -0.1241    0.6715    0.4889    0.2939
    1.4897   -1.2075    1.0347   -0.7873
    1.4090    0.7172    0.7269    0.8884
    1.4172    1.6302   -0.3034   -1.1471

a(:,:,1,2) =
   -1.0689    0.3252   -0.1022   -0.8649
   -0.8095   -0.7549   -0.2414   -0.0301
   -2.9443    1.3703    0.3192   -0.1649
    1.4384   -1.7115    0.3129    0.6277

a(:,:,2,2) =
    1.0933   -1.2141   -0.7697   -1.0891
    1.1093   -1.1135    0.3714    0.0326
   -0.8637   -0.0068   -0.2256    0.5525
    0.0774    1.5326    1.1174    1.1006

a(:,:,1,3) =
    1.5442   -1.0616   -0.1924   -1.4224
    0.0859    2.3505    0.8886    0.4882
   -1.4916   -0.6156   -0.7648   -0.1774
   -0.7423    0.7481   -1.4023   -0.1961

a(:,:,2,3) =
    1.4193   -0.8045    0.2157    0.7223
    0.2916    0.6966   -1.1658    2.5855
    0.1978    0.8351   -1.1480   -0.6669
    1.5877   -0.2437    0.1049    0.1873

[d1 d2 d3 d4]=size(a);
aa=reshape(a,[],d4)';
b(:,:,1)=[0 0 1 0;0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 ;0 0 0 0]
b(:,:,2)=[0 0 1 0;0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 ;0 0 0 0]
bb=reshape(b,1,[]);
aa(:,find(~bb))=NaN;
c=reshape(aa,d1,d2,d3,d4);

c(:,:,1,1) =
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN

c(:,:,2,1) =
       NaN       NaN    3.5784       NaN
       NaN       NaN   -0.1022       NaN
       NaN       NaN   -0.1924       NaN
       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN

c(:,:,1,2) =
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN

c(:,:,2,2) =
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN

c(:,:,1,3) =
       NaN       NaN    0.4889       NaN
       NaN       NaN   -0.7697       NaN
       NaN       NaN    0.2157       NaN
       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN

c(:,:,2,3) =    
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Why are the nonnan elements in `c` in a different position relative to their position in the original array `a`?

I was expecting the output

```
c(:,:,1,1) =
    NaN    NaN    3.5784    NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN

c(:,:,2,1) =
    NaN    NaN    0.4889    NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN

c(:,:,1,2) =
    NaN    NaN   -0.1022    NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN

c(:,:,2,2) =
    NaN    NaN   -0.7697    NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN

c(:,:,1,3) =
    NaN    NaN   -0.1924    NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN

c(:,:,2,3) =
    NaN    NaN    0.2157    NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN
```

Comment: not clear to me what you're asking.  Instead of `randn`, provide a sample of `a` and the output `c` that you're expecting for that `a` alongwith the explanation how and why you should be getting that output

Comment: @Sardar Usama: I have updated my question with a sample output

Comment: Apparently `b`  decides the nan and non-nan entries in the output but why are there two slices of `b`? Please explain how your output is dependent on the inputs

Comment: Seeing the expected output, your question makes sense to me only if `b` has *only one* slice i.e. `b(:,:,1)`.  Please explain how  you expect `b` to work

Comment: @Sardar Usama: Essentially b is supposed to select the elements in the [1st row, 3rd column] for all 3rd and 4th dimensions. In the desired output, the non-nan elements remain in the original positions of a, but my code seems to mess this organization, and I don't understand why

Comment: it is unclear which elements are affected by `b(:,:,1)` and which are affected by `b(:,:,2)` since both `b(:,:,1)` and `b(:,:,2)` are same and you haven't explained that in any form

Comment: @Sardar Usama: b has two slices in order to select both slices of a in the 3rd dimension. Sorry I don't know how to explain it better.

Comment: Choose different values for the slices of `b`. Currently both slices are same. And then update your expected output accordingly

Comment: @SardarUsama: `a` has sizes `[4,4,2,3]`, and `b` has sizes `[4,4,2]`, so it's supposed to match the first three dimensions of `a`. The `:` indexing in `aa` must then match the 4th dimension of size `3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I make these changes to your code, the output matches your expected output:

```
a = randn(4,4,2,3);
[d1 d2 d3 d4] = size(a);
aa = reshape(a,[],d4); % <-- NOTE! no transpose
b = [0 0 1 0;0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 ;0 0 0 0];
b(:,:,2) = [0 0 1 0;0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 ;0 0 0 0];
bb = reshape(b,1,[]);
aa(find(~bb),:) = NaN; % <-- NOTE! swapped indexing
c = reshape(aa,d1,d2,d3,d4);
```

By transposing the array `aa`, and not transposing back later, all elements ended up in a different location.

---

Edit: @Sardar Usama makes a good point in the comment below. You can accomplish the same thing like this:

```
c = a;
c(repmat(~b,[1,1,1,3])) = NaN
```

(and probably on other ways too, e.g. he's suggesting multiplication which would accomplish the same thing.)

Comment: Thanks, it works great! I suppose I'm still not very clear how to use the reshape function...

Comment: @HappyPy: You seem to be doing fine with the `reshape` function. I just noticed that you tried to reshape the `aa` array back to the sizes of `a`, and that will not work after transposing, which reorders data in memory (the reshape doesn't copy the data at all).

Comment: @Cris Luengo: Many thanks for the explanation, I think I understand now.

Comment: I have a rough idea that you may be looking for this: `b(b==0)= NaN;` `c=a;`
`c(:,:,1,:)=b(:,:,1).*c(:,:,1,:);`
`c(:,:,2,:)=b(:,:,2).*c(:,:,2,:);` (with implicit expansion)

Comment: I understood the question after reading your answer. The question would have been clearer if `b(:,:,1)` and `b(:,:,2)` were not chosen the same